# React bootstrap Carousel not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm new using react bootstrap, and I'm trying to use a Carousel, however it's giving me this bug of the last slide disappearing when changing slide:

[image]

Here I'm sliding and that happens, also the slide is delayed, here's my code:

```
import React from "react";
import {Carousel} from "react-bootstrap";
import perro from "../perro.jpg";
const CarouselContainer = props => {
    return (
        <Carousel>
            <Carousel.Item>
                <img
                className="d-block w-100"   
                src={perro}
                alt="First slide"
                />
                <Carousel.Caption>
                <h3>First slide label</h3>
                <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
                </Carousel.Caption>
            </Carousel.Item>
            <Carousel.Item>
                <img
                className="d-block w-100"
                src={perro}
                alt="Second slide"
                />
                <Carousel.Caption>
                <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </Carousel.Caption>
            </Carousel.Item>
        </Carousel>
    );
}
```

Comment: Could you share the code with styles in stackbiltz or codesandbox?

Answer (score 3):

import bootstrap CSS in page, then it will work.

`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

Comment: Yes. This worked. I added this to App.js instead of each component

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answer is going to help you, but i have the same issue with react bootstrap, and the error was in my css when the elements inside the carousel had a flex display. For any reason that property causes that blank slide just before the scroll effect. If that doesn't solve the problem, you can try changing the react-bootstrap carousel to the only [bootstrap carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/).

First import the [bootstrap.bundle.min.js](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/) script in your
index.html:

```
<script async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

*Note that this bootstrap script is for 5.1 version, so if you are using another version, just search the script in the documentation for that version.*

Then, put your bootstrap carousel into your component and keep in mind that the flex display causes the error.

I hope i've helped. Sorry if it wasn't clear, but is my first time answering here :D

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too when I added my own indicators to the carousel. I also had a dynamic array of items that had to be presented in the carousel. It seems it happened to you for some reason too. In my case, react-bootstrap's carousel overran the list of items when it was sliding. I handled it controlling the sliding using the activeIndex and onSelect properties for the Carousel component.

In your case, you can try something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import {Carousel} from "react-bootstrap";
import perro from "../perro.jpg";

function CarouselContainer() {
  //critical to set initial state to zero
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  const handleSelect = (selectedIndex, e) => {
    //adjust index to 0 if greater than index of last slide or less than zero
    //slide indexes are zero-based so yourLasSlideIndex would be 1 I guess
    if (selectedIndex >= yourLastSlideIndex+1 || selectedIndex < 0 ){
            this.setIndex(0);
        } else if (selectedIndex !== index) {
            setIndex(selectedIndex);
        }
  };

  return (
    <Carousel activeIndex={index} onSelect={handleSelect}>
      <Carousel.Item>
                <img
                className="d-block w-100"   
                src={perro}
                alt="First slide"
                />
                <Carousel.Caption>
                <h3>First slide label</h3>
                <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
                </Carousel.Caption>
            </Carousel.Item>
            <Carousel.Item>
                <img
                className="d-block w-100"
                src={perro}
                alt="Second slide"
                />
                <Carousel.Caption>
                <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </Carousel.Caption>
            </Carousel.Item>
    </Carousel>
  );
}

render(<CarouselContainer />);
```

You might also be able to control it using the onSlid or onSlide callback properties, but not sure.